# Decorators with React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, ecmascript-next

I am very excited about the ability to use the `@myDecorator` syntax (using babel). I am trying to decorate one of the life cycle functions, specifically `componentWillMount`, and check the `props` and `context` of the component within the decorator. However, I seem to not be able to access either the `props` or `context`. I am not sure if this is sort of an anti pattern or if I am just going about this wrong.

Small Example:

```
// TestComponent.jsx
import checkProps from 'checkProps.js';

class TestComponent extends React.Component {
    @checkProps
    componentWillMount() {
        // Do something.
    }

    render() {
       return <div>My Component</div>
    } 
}
```

and

```
// checkProps.js
export function checkProps(target) {
    console.log(target.props);
}
```

I have also tried arrow functions for the decorator and checking `this`, but I don't think decorators compose things to work that way.

I have also tried making my decorator a factory and passing in `this.props` and `this.context` but `this` is undefined when decorating a component life cycle function.

Comment: I believe the decorator needs to be added to the class, not the constructor.

Comment: @moderndegree it exposes the same `Component` object when you decorate the class. I should have also explained I tried that as well sorry.

Comment: @Brandon I am not doing anything in there yet. I just want to be able to access the props from within it as shown at the bottom of the code example with the comment `checkProps.js`. I will separate them so it is more clear.

Comment: Can you please try *returning* a function from the decorator: `export function checkProps() { return function(target) { console.log(target.props); }}` and of course use it as such (note the parentheses): `@checkProps() componentWillMount() { ... }`.

Comment: Which version of babel are you using? Babel v6 doesn't support decorators.

Comment: @DaurenAkilbekov babel core 6.7.2.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos like I mentioned, I have already tried setting the decorator up as a factory. It yields the same lack of props.

Comment: Decorators are **not** part of ES2016.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<strike>ES7</strike> ECMAScript Decorators have [the same API as `Object.defineProperty(target, name, descriptor)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) so the `target` parameter is your class at the time your decorator is applied, not at the time it is called by `React`. To influence what the decorator is doing at runtime you have to modify `descriptor.value` that is the actual function that is decorated:

```
export function checkProps(target, name, descriptor) {
    // Save the original method, it'd be a good idea
    // to check that it really is a function
    const decoratee = descriptor.value;

    // Modify the descriptor to return our decorator
    // function instead of the original
    descriptor.value = function decorated(...args) {
        // Do something before ...
        console.log('before: ' + name, this.props, args);

        // Calling the decorated method on this object
        // with some arguments that could have been 
        // augmented by this decorator
        decoratee.apply(this, args);

        // Do something after ...
        console.log('after: ' + name);
    };
} 

// Or if you wanted to use a factory function to supply some configuration
// to the decorator you can do it this way

export function checkProps(config) {
    return function configurableCheckProps(target, name, descriptor) {
        // Save the original method, it'd be a good idea
        // to check that it really is a function
        const decoratee = descriptor.value;

        if (config.someOption) {
            // Do something based on the config
        }

        // Modify the descriptor to return our decorator
        // function instead of the original
        descriptor.value = function decorated(...args) {
            // Do something before ...
            console.log('before: ' + name, this.props, args);

            if (config.someOption) {
                // Do something based on the config
            }

            // Calling the decorated method on this object
            // with some arguments that could have been 
            // augmented by this decorator
            decoratee.apply(this, args);

            // Do something after ...
            console.log('after: ' + name);
        };
    };
}
```

Here's [an example that also modifies the behavior of a method](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/decorators-es7/read-write/src/scripts/libs/ReadWrite/ReadWrite.js) that demonstrates this more thoroughly.

Hope this helps. Happy coding!

EDIT: As a commenter pointed out, decorators are not part of ES7 but as of March 2016 [the proposal is still in Stage 1](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262#current-proposals), my bad

EDIT2: As of June 2018 the proposal is in [the proposal is still in Stage 2](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262#current-proposals), we're getting closer

Comment: Glad I could help - a good time for a refresher on the topic for myself as well

Comment: Decorators are **not** part of ES2016.

Comment: @FelixKling you're of course right, it was scheduled for ES7 but as of now it [is still stage 1](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262) - there's also a [nice writeup on the decorators proposal](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators/blob/master/README.md)